# Use a function to insert 2 queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am trying to write a single function in my php script that adds a new page into my database and updates the navigation table at the same time. For some reason both queries are failing, and I'm not sure what else I should do. 
This is my add_content function call:

```
elseif ($react == "add_content") {
    echo 'add content';
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    if (!empty($title) && !empty($content) && !empty($page)) {
        addcontent($title, $content, $page);
    } else {
    echo 'not enough info';
    }
```

and this is my function:

```
function addcontent($title, $content, $page) {
global $db;
$query1 = "INSERT INTO `content`(`title`, `content`) VALUES (:title, :content)";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `navigation` ('page', 'content_id') SELECT :page, c.content_id  FROM content c WHERE title=:page;";
try {
    $stat = $db->prepare($query1);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query2);
    $stat->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stat->bindParam(':content', $content);
    $stat->bindParam(':page', $page);
    $stat->execute($query1);
    $stmt->execute($query2);
    $result = "<strong>$title</strong> added<p>";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $result = "$title deltetion failed";
}
```

}

I know the two queries work because I've already tested them with dummy information, it's just getting them to work inside of this function that's causing the problem.

I'm not sure if this is needed, but just in case, this is my table to add content:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="react" value="add_content">
            <input type="hidden" name="page|title" value="admin">
            <div align="center"><center><p>ADD A New Page<br>
             Title: <input type="text" name="title|page" size="20"><br>
             Content: <input type="text" name="content" size="20"><br>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit"></p></center></div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `navigation` ('page', 'content_id') 
SELECT :page, c.content_id  FROM content c WHERE title=:page;";
       ^ column name marker
```

You can't use markers for column names. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
>   (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column
>   in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value. However, they are not
>   allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names), in the select
>   list that names the columns to be returned by a SELECT statement), or
>   to specify both operands of a binary operator such as the = equal
>   sign. The latter restriction is necessary because it would be
>   impossible to determine the parameter type. In general, parameters are
>   legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements, and not in
>   Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

If you're trying to select the constant `$page` you can select `c.title` because your where condition guarantees that it will be equal to `$page`.

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `navigation` ('page', 'content_id') 
SELECT c.title, c.content_id  FROM content c WHERE title=:page;";
```

Also, you're binding `$page` to the wrong statement

```
$stat->bindParam(':page', $page);
```

Change it to

```
$stmt->bindParam(':page', $page);
   ^
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Do you have any suggestions on what I should use instead then? because I just tested it with quotes and it still isn't working. EDIT: NEvermind, I just saw the rest. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: @Jess just realized `c.title` is the same as `$page` so inserting `c.title` will give you the same results. but are you sure you want the value from `$page` and not `content.page` (in which case you just need to replace `:page` with `c.page`)?

Comment: I need the value from navigation.page, because there is no content.page at all. My tables are set up as content (content_id, title, content) and navigation (nav_id, page, content_id) Since my nav's content id is a foreign key, I'm executing my navigation query second to pull out the content_id by using the page/title value because they should be exactly the same. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Jess it looks like you're binding `$page` to the wrong statement, see update

Comment: I think I must have broken something somewhere else, because for some reason, it's still not working. Maybe I'll try seperating them into their own seperate functions and run them one at a time instead.